# Retrieve Array in Subdocument MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, subdocument

I have a Users model structure somewhat like this:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true },
  password: String,

  todosDo: [models.Do.schema],
}
```

And the child "Do" schema somewhat like this (in a different file):

```
const doSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, default : ''},
  user: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  createdAt: {type : Date, default : Date.now}
});
```

And I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve the todosDo array for the signed in user. This is what I've got so far:

```
// Get all "Do" todos from DB
// Experimenting to find todos from certain user
  User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, user){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
      doTodos = user.todosDo, // this obviously doesn't work, just an idea of what I was going for
      console.log(doTodos); 
      finished();
    }
  });
```

Am I referencing the child/parent wrong or am I just not retrieving the array right? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is that comma after `users.todosDo` actually in your code? If it is, your inadvertantly setting `doTodos` to `console.log()`  which is `undefined`.

Comment: @Mike It is, but I defined doTodos like this : `var doTodos = {};` before getting all "Do" todos from DB. Or is that not what you're referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help everybody! My problem was that I needed to push all the newly created todos in the post route to todosDo, so then I could retrieve them at the get route. Everything's working now!

Answer (score 0):

As far I guess you may want to edit as raw js objects so you need to use `lean()` function. without using `lean()` function **user** is mongoose object so you can't modify it.

can try this one:

```
User.findById(req.user.id)
  .lean()
  .exec(function (err, user) {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(400).send({msg:'Error occurred'});
    } 
    if(!user) {
      return res.status(400).send({msg:'User Not found'});
    }

    doTodos = user.todosDo;
    console.log(user.todosDo); // check original todos
    console.log(doTodos);
    return res.status(200).send({doTodos : doTodos }); // return doTodos 

  });
```

and to refer **child schema** in **parent schema** from different model you can access a Model's schema via its `schema` property.

say in `doSchema.js` file

```
const doSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, default : ''},
  user: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  createdAt: {type : Date, default : Date.now}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model( 'DoSchema', doSchema );
```

in `user.js` file

```
var DoModel = require('./doSchema');// exact path
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true },
  password: String,

  todosDo: [DoModel.schema],
}
```

Comment: @shishab Thanks for you answer, but when I try to run it, it just keeps loading and doesn't display anything. But, I know that the app has gotten to the console.log because it prints out doTodos which is still an empty array.

Comment: keeps loading because it didn't return anything. updated answer. Ensure that you have data in `todosDo` in `user` collection.